# Prevent duplicate entry with msg box showing serial number of value already present using vba

Tags: excel, duplicates, vba

I want to create a vba code to prevent duplicate entry that also tell me the location where it is already present. E.g. in my sheet it I type 'Jimmy' in cell D13 or anywhere in column D then a `MsgBox` will warn me showing "The entered Name is already exists at serial number 4."

[image: This is the screen shot of my sheet]

I am trying this formula but doesn't work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 2 And Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then

    If Evaluate("Countif(D:D," & Target.Address & ")") > 1 Then
        MsgBox Target.Value & " is a duplicate entry.  It will be removed.", vbExclamation, "Data Entry Editor" & "(INDEX(C7:C23,MATCH(target.Value,D7:D23,0))"
        Range(Target.Address).ClearContents

    End If         
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It is working half i.e it remove the duplicate entry but doesn't tell at what serial number it is already present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the answer provided by @ShaiRado is certainly correct it is missing a small piece and does not point out in which line the (dupe) name exists already. So, here is another solution which includes:

1. the desired feature of indicating the duplicate row and
2. also allows for duplicates in the middle of the list. So, if you were to change in your list the name for S. No. 2 from Mukesh to
   Jimmy.
3. Finally, the sub has been changed to allow for editing multiple cells at once (selecting several rows and pressing `del` or inserting several names / rows at once).

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim arrList As Variant, cell As Range
Dim rowLast As Long, searchRow As Long

For Each cell In Target
    If cell.Column = 4 And Trim(cell.Value2) <> vbNullString Then
        rowLast = cell.Parent.Cells(cell.Parent.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp).Row
        arrList = cell.Parent.Range("D1:D" & rowLast).Value2
            For searchRow = LBound(arrList) To UBound(arrList)
                If searchRow <> cell.Row Then
                    If arrList(UBound(arrList), 1) = arrList(searchRow, 1) Then
                        cell.Parent.Activate
                        Union(cell, cell.Parent.Range("C" & searchRow & ":F" & searchRow)).Select
                        MsgBox "This name exists already in row " & searchRow & _
                            Chr(10) & "   with the S. No. " & searchRow - 6 & _
                            Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "This name will be now removed..."
                        Application.EnableEvents = False
                        cell.ClearContents
                        Application.EnableEvents = True
                    End If
                End If
            Next searchRow
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you want to check for values in Column D, but in your code you are checking for `If Target.Column = 2 And..` , it needs to be `If Target.Column = 4`.

Also, you can use the `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` to see if there will be duplicates in column D.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 4 And Len(Target.Value) > 0 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("D:D"), Target.Value) > 1 Then
        MsgBox Target.Value & " is a duplicate entry.  It will be removed.", vbExclamation, "Data Entry Editor" & "(INDEX(C7:C23,MATCH(Target.Value,D7:D23,0))"
        Target.ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

excel has this functionality built into the ribbon...

use conditional formatting - to flag the duplicates 
& data validation for pop-up notification

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/prevent-duplicate-entries.html

Comment: It doesn't tell cell address that already contains the value.